# Let $\|f_n\|_2\leq1$ and $f_n\to f$ in measure then $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$ norm where $1\leq p<2$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\|f_n\|_2\leq1$ and $f_n\to f$ in measure then $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$ norm where $1\leq p<2$. Edit: We are in finite measure!

My proof:

By extended Holders we have that $\|f_n\chi_E\|_p\leq\|f_n\|_2\mu(E)^\frac{2p}{2-p}$ Thus the sequence is uniformly integrable in $L^p$. Hence by Vitali, we are done. It seems too easy and the proof i found online is much longer.